# How to use fopen, feof, and fread to manipulate multiple files?

Tags: php, xml-parsing, fopen, fread, feof

I have a file (fullsoccer.txt) which has 500 links (online links for XML files) I call those links and then I pass each one to a function that open the link then read the content and then passing the content to parsing function (xml_parser) to parse the content and save it in my database. my problem is that the function is parsing and saving the last file only. I try to debug the code and find that all links are right and being opened but just the last one is being parsed I need your help on this is the problem with my code? or does fopen and fread in my loop receiving the second opening request before finishing the first reading request? 
this is my code:

```
function doParse($parser_object) {
  $links=file("./fullsoccer.TXT");
  foreach($links as $link)
  {
      set_time_limit(0);
      //echo 'reading '.$link."\n";
      $fp = fopen($link, "r");
      if ($fp!==false)
      {
          //loop through data
          while ($data = fread($fp, 4096)) {
              //parse the fragment
              xml_parse($parser_object, $data, feof($fp));
              //echo $data;
          }
          //echo "\n";
          fclose($fp);
      } else {
          echo 'Cannot Open Link '.$link."\n";
      }
  }
}
```

help my on this because I have been living with it for really a long time, please

Answer (score 0):

can you try with [`file_get_contents();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) ?

its easier..

```
  if (($data = file_get_contents($link)) !== FALSE) {
          xml_parse($parser_object, $data/*, feof($fp)*/);
  } else {
      echo 'Cannot Open Link '.$link."\n";
  }
```

also enable `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set("display_errors",1);` for some more light..

Comment: I use this code but the problem is still the same . It just read the content of the last link in my links, I am getting crazy

Comment: are you sure you're getting all the links from your .txt file? you verified it with `print_r();` just before the loop ? the code is too simple to have something hidden..

Comment: yes this is the first think I get sure of it and I am sure that all links are served

Comment: cannot think anything else than checking the result code of `xml_parse();` (0=fail) and analyzing it with `xml_error_string($code);`

Answer (score -1):

if you need to read text file you can use it like below

```
<?php
$file = fopen("fullsoccer.txt", "r");
$links = array();

while (!feof($file)) {
   $links[] = fgets($file);
}

fclose($links);

var_dump($links);
?>
```

Comment: No the problem not in the text file I read it perfectly. I want to read the content of each link in the text file.